# Unable to start eth0 interface on raspberry pi4 model B

Tags: raspberry-pi4

I could not find any useful resource. How to restart eth0 properly. I'm running ubuntu server 22.04.1 on raspberry pi 4 model B. I tried running `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` it did not work.

`eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000`

Here is network configure on raspberry pi

```
pi@homeserver:/etc/network$ ls
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d  interfaces
pi@homeserver:/etc/network$ cat interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
pi@homeserver:/etc/network$ ls
if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d  interfaces
pi@homeserver:/etc/network$
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ifup eth0` just as it states in your post, but that is not going to happen if there is no carrier, no cable. It should all be automatic if a working cable has been inserted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.  Try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/